# how to interpret the output information while installing program in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, installation, output, llvm

I was installing llvm and I noticed this on the shell:

> llvm[5]: Compiling SemaAccess.cpp for Release+Asserts build

what does "5" stand for ?

Thanks in advance for answering my noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Level of make in llvm, represented with MAKELEVEL variable in make.
in file Makefile.rules see definition of EchoCmd:

checkout:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion

duplicate question.

[meanning of llvm[n] when compiling llvm, where n is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530769/meanning-of-llvmn-when-compiling-llvm-where-n-is-an-integer)